# (VBA Excel) Trying to collect data from sheets with macro, error 91

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a workbook with two sheets, the first containing a person's first and last name, and the second containing usernames (person's first initial of first name and full last name, ex: John Smith -> jsmith).
The second sheet has information in the 5 columns to the right of each username and I need to collect that information and place it with the corresponding name on the first sheet.
Right now, running this results in:

```
Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

I've gotten the body of the code to run when it wasn't in a while loop. So I know that the code works when entering individual cells. However, my implementation of variable cells won't behave with it.
Here's the code:

```
Sub Macro()

' set up counter

    Dim rownum As Long
    rownum = 1

    Do While rownum < 273
        Dim cellA As String
        Dim cellB As String
        Dim cellC As String

' change cells depending on current rownum
        cellA = "A" & CStr(rownum)
        cellB = "B" & CStr(rownum)
        cellC = "C" & CStr(rownum)

        Dim rngA As String
        Dim rngB As String
        Dim rngAB As String

' select sheet and collect first initial of first name and full last name
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        first = Left(Range(cellA).Value, 1)
        last = Range(cellB).Value
        searchname = first & last

' select sheet with info and find the row with username
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select

' ***this is where the issue is***
        Cells.Find(What:=searchname, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
' ***this is where the issue is***

' copy the info and paste it into the first sheet
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 5).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range(cellC).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        rownum = rownum + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or knows a cleaner approach, that would be great.

Comment: I don't think you need to be using the Let command here, just use `cellA = "A" & Cstr(rownum)` (converting the rownumber to a string to concatenate).

Comment: Oops, I had those there from earlier. I removed them though and still had the same issue. I edited it to show where the issue was occurring.

Comment: Right now, there is a list of names in one sheet, and usernames + additional info in the same row as the username in the other. They are not in any particular order, are they? That's why you have to search for the correspondance?

Comment: Yes. That is correct, David.

Comment: Do you have any possibility of having duplicates, and do you have a solution in mind if it happens? example Joe Smith and John Smith, what happens with their email?

Comment: I do not, unfortunately. Some of the names might not be on the second sheet and I'll have to manually enter them, so I'll be looking back over cases like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the return value of `.Find()` without checking to see if you actually found anything on this line:

```
    Cells.Find(What:=searchname, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

If `.Find()` doesn't return anything, there isn't anything to activate - thus Error 91.

Try saving the return to a variable, check to see if it is nothing, then do whatever you need to do based on if you found it or not:

```
Dim result As Range
Set result = Cells.Find(What:=searchname, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not result Is Nothing Then
    result.Activate
    'Found code
Else
    'Not found code.
End If
```

That said, you should usually avoid using `.Activate` and `.Select` - instead, grab references and work with the objects directly instead of using the global Active objects.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I did as you suggested and it worked perfectly.
As for the `.Activate` and `.Select`, I had no idea. I just recorded a macro and worked from the bits I found there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to use copy and paste and can just set the values directly. You can also work with the `.Cells` property of the worksheets to avoid having to create the cell strings.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i as Integer
    Dim rownum As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    rownum = 1

    Do While rownum < 273
'collect first initial of first name and full last name
        first = Left(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rownum, 1).Value, 1)
        last = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rownum, 2)
        searchname = first & last

'copy values to first sheet
        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(What:=searchname, MatchCase:=False)
        For i = 1 To 5 Step 1
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rownum, i + 2).Value = rng.Offset(, i).Value
        Next i

        rownum = rownum + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, bernie.
I'm still getting the Error 91 though, this time on:
`Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rownum, i + 2).Value = rng.Offset(, i).Value`